# SPFX - How to get data from _spPageContextInfo

Tags: spfx, react

Object _spPageContextInfo  is available in my DOM tree. How to get his properties with react.JS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too get same problem, and i resolved it by using the `SPComponentLoader.loadScript`, please refer below code snippet

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/init.js', {
    globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
})
.then((): Promise<{}> => {
    return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
    globalExportsName: 'Sys'
});})
.then((): Promise<{}> => {
    return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
    globalExportsName: 'SP'
});})
.then((): Promise<{}> => {
    return SPComponentLoader.loadScript(siteColUrl + '/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
    globalExportsName: 'SP'
});})
.then((): void => {
    let spContext: SP.ClientContext =new SP.ClientContext(siteColUrl);
    //place your logic here.
});
```

Make sure to add the **microsoft-ajax** and **sharepoint** in your **tsconfig.json** file like below,

```
"types": [     
  "webpack-env",
  "microsoft-ajax",
  "sharepoint"
]
```

Also, add the below packages in your package.json file and make sure to restore the npm packages.

```
"@types/microsoft-ajax": "0.0.33",
"@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
"@types/sharepoint": "^2013.1.6",
```